# PowerShell is failling to auto import module, if the command uses a 'unapproved verb'

Tags: powershell

if I have a module called `foo`

```
C:\Users\gary\Documents\PowerShell\Modules\foo\foo.psm1
C:\Users\gary\Documents\PowerShell\Modules\foo\foo.psd1
```

With the content of `foo.psd1` being:

```
@{
    ModuleVersion = '0.0.1'
    FunctionsToExport = @('*')
    RootModule           = 'foo.psm1'
}
```

and `foo.psm1`:

```
Function Encode-Path{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, Mandatory)]
        $Path
    )
    Process {"Some process"}
    End {"Ending..."}
}
Function Decode-Path{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, Mandatory)]
        $Path
    )
    Process {"Some process"}
    End {"Ending..."}
}
```

Simply calling the `Encode-Path` at the shell will fail with:

```
Encode-Path: The term 'Encode-Path' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I sometimes fix this by calling `pwsh.exe` within the session and then:

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable
```

but it too sometimes does not even work and when it does there is a long delay, as it will import every module on my system.

I know this issue is being caused by my use of unapproved verb. I really don't like the `<verb><noun>` at all. I don't work with a team, I just use PowerShell to make my life easy, so please don't just suggest I get on board with it.

Searching around I have not found any solution for this, I just keep coming across solutions for `Import-Module -DisableNameChecking` which is addresses a separate issue, which is to supress warning messages about "unapproved verbs"

I am just looking for a way to auto import modules as I invoke their commands, Ideally avoid having to import all modules at once.

Comment: The unapproved-verb warning is unrelated to the command discovery issue. Update the manifest to `FunctionsToExport = @('Decode-Path','Encode-Path')` and PowerShell should happily autoload the module

Comment: @Mathias, `FunctionsToExport = @('*')` also works with auto-loading - it's just slower, and therefore the recommendation is to explicitly enumerate all functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your symptom isn't consistent with your problem description / sample code.
**PowerShell's de facto behavior** is as follows (written as of v7.4.x):

- [Auto-loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules#module-autoloading) happens for any module placed in one of the directories listed in [`$env:PSModulePath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_psmodulepath).
- When auto-loading happens, there is *no* warning for exported commands that do not adhere to PowerShell's naming convention, i.e. commands that do not use the `<verb>-<noun>` convention, with `<verb>` needing to be one of the [approved verbs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands).
- By contrast, *explicitly* loading (importing) a given module that exports commands with nonstandard names *does* generate a warning:

  - If [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module) is used for explicit importing, you can use the `-DisableNameChecking` switch to *silence* the warning.
  - If [`using module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Using#module-syntax) is used, you can NOT silence the warning.
- **If you want to ensure that no warning is *ever* emitted**:

  - Give your functions a *standard* name to begin with - which you must export *too*, however.
  - Define - and export - *aliases* for those functions, using the desired nonstandard names (alias names are not subject to the warning) - see the bottom section for an example.

---

In other words: if your module is located in one of the directories in `$env:PSModulePath`, loading it *implicitly* by invoking one of its exported commands will *not* result in a warning.

---

> `Get-Module -ListAvailable` [...] when it does there is a long delay, as it will import every module on my system.

- `-ListAvailable` does *not* import every module - it simply reports all modules that are *discoverable* via `$env:PSModulePath`, along with their exported commands an aliases.
- However, you can help *speed up* discovery by *avoiding [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) expressions*; e.g., instead of using `FunctionsToExport = @('*')` in your [module manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Module_Manifests), enumerate the functions to export *explicitly*: `FunctionsToExport = @('Encode-Path', 'Decode-Path')

---

###### Self-contained sample code that demonstrates combining *arbitrarily named aliases* with *functions with standard names*:

```
# Create a directory for a `sample` module in the current user's module location:

# Get the root dir. of the current user's modules.
$currUserModuleRootDir = ("$(Split-Path $PROFILE)\Modules", "$HOME/.local/share/powershell/Modules")[$env:OS -ne 'Windows_NT']

# Create a 'sample' subdirectory for it, to create a module by that name.
$sampleModuleDir = New-Item -Force -Type Directory (Join-Path $currUserModuleRootDir sample)

# Create the root script module (`*.psm1`):
@'
  # Define the functions with *standard* names.
  Function ConvertTo-__Path {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, Mandatory)]
        $Path
    )
    Process {"Some process"}
    End {"Ending..."}
  }

  Function ConvertFrom-__Path {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, Mandatory)]
        $Path
    )
    Process {"Some process"}
    End {"Ending..."}
  }

  # Now define *alias* with the desired - nonstandard - names:
  Set-Alias Encode-Path ConvertTo-__Path
  Set-Alias Decode-Path ConvertFrom-__Path

'@ > (Join-Path $sampleModuleDir sample.psm1)
         
# Create the module's manifest:
@'
  @{
    ModuleVersion = '0.0.1'
    FunctionsToExport = @('ConvertTo-__Path', 'ConvertFrom-__Path')
    AliasesExport = @('Encode-Path', 'Decode-Path')
    RootModule           = 'sample.psm1'
  }
'@ > (Join-Path $sampleModuleDir sample.psd1)
```

After running the above:

- Aliases `Encode-Path` and `Decode-Path` should be *auto-discovered*
- Explicitly running `Import-Module sample` or `using module sample` should work *without warning*.

If you later want to *remove* the sample module, run the following (you may have to run `Remove-Module sample` first):

```
Remove-Item -Recurse (Join-Path ("$(Split-Path $PROFILE)\Modules", "$HOME/.local/share/powershell/Modules")[$env:OS -ne 'Windows_NT'] sample)
```

Comment: This answers quite a few questions, I have been pushing to the back of my head for some time. Cheers mate.